# inconsistency between repl and test runner

Tags: testing, clojure, macros

I'm having some issues with testing a clojure macro. When I put the code through the repl, it behaves as expected, but when I try to expect this behavior in a test, I'm getting back nil instead. I have a feeling it has to do with how the test runner handles macroexpansion, but I'm not sure what exactly is going on. Any advice/alternative ways to test this code is appreciated.

Here is a simplified example of the macro I'm trying to test

```
(defmacro macro-with-some-validation
  [-name- & forms]
    (assert-symbols [-name-])
    `(defn ~-name- [] (println "You passed the validation")))

  (macroexpand-1 (read-string "(macro-with-some-validation my-name (forms))"))
  ;; ->
  (clojure.core/defn my-name [] (clojure.core/println "You passed the validation"))
```

When passed into the repl

```
  (macroexpand-1 (read-string "(macro-with-some-validation 'not-symbol (forms))"))
  ;; ->
  rulesets.core-test=> Exception Non-symbol passed in to function.  chibi-1-0-0.core/assert-symbols (core.clj:140)
```

But when put through a test

```
  (deftest macro-with-some-validation-bad
    (testing "Passing in a non-symbol to the macro"
(is (thrown? Exception
             (macroexpand-1 (read-string "(macro-with-some-validation 'not-symbol (forms))"))))))

  ;; after a lein test ->
  FAIL in (macro-with-some-validation-bad) (core_test.clj:50)
  Passing in a non-symbol to the macro
  expected: (thrown? Exception (macroexpand-1 (read-string "(macro-with-some-validation 'not-symbol (forms))")))
    actual: nil
```

Thanks.

Edit: forgot to include the source for assert-symbols in case it matters

```
(defn assert-symbol [symbol]
  (if (not (instance? clojure.lang.Symbol symbol))
        (throw (Exception. "Non-symbol passed in to function."))))

(defn assert-symbols [symbols]
  (if (not (every? #(instance? clojure.lang.Symbol %) symbols))
    (throw (Exception. "Non-symbol passed in to function."))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing my read-strings to be ` instead, I'm able to get the code working again. Still strange that read-string wasn't working correctly, though. Thanks for the help.