# Inconsistent test result between repl and regular file

Tags: clojure

Consider this test:

```
(deftest test
  (is (= false (nil? (do
                       (def sym 0)
                       (resolve 'sym))))))
```

Put it into a repl and it will pass. Put it instead in a file and now it wont. How so ?

I tried messing with namespaces but without success.

I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585615/inconsistency-between-repl-and-test-runner) but it doesn't help me.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your results; when I prefix your code with `(require '[clojure.test :refer [deftest is]])`, I get the same result whether I run it in a REPL or in a [Boot script](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Scripts); could you be more specific?

Comment: Looks like it should work indeed. Maybe try posting the failing message and the test command (`lein test`, `boot test`)?